# True or False -> O(m+n) = O(m)

Tags: graph, asymptotic-complexity

Let

- m = Number of Edges in a graph
- n = Number of Vertices in a graph

Assume graph G(V,E) is undirected and connected.

What I did is substitute m with (n*(n-1)/2), since that is the maximum possible edge in terms of number of nodes.

So, I found it to be true,

But, the real answer is false.

Can some one explain conceptually what is meant to be comparing to Big-Oh complexities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is is correct that the number of edges `m` is bounded by

```
m <= (n*(n-1)/2)
```

and

```
n*(n-1)/2 = (n^2-n)/2
```

which means that the reasoning in the question yields

```
m+n <= (n^2-n)/1+n = O(n^2)
```

which is the same complexity as `O(m)`; However stating the complexity of an algorithm in a way which takes explicitly into account the number of edges and the number of nodes is more precise than using the worst-case bound of `(n^2-n)/2`.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: **true**

The graph is connected => `m >= n-1` => `m = n-1+k` where `k >= 0`.

But `m <= n(n-1)/2` because you don't need more edges if you have an edge between every 2 nodes. => `n-1+k <= n(n-1)/2` => `k <= (n-1)(n/2-1)` => `k <= (n-1)(n-2)/2`.

So, we have `m = n - 1 + k` where `0 <= k <= (n-1)(n-2)/2` ; `k` represents the number of edges which exceed the minimum number necessary for connectivity.

```
O(m+n) = O(n-1+k+n) = O(2n-1+k) = O(2n+k) = a

O(m) = O(n-1+k) = O(n+k) = b
```

Now, let's take 3 situations:

- `lim(n->inf) n/k = 0`

  `a = O(k(2n/k + 1)) = O(k)`

  `b = O(k(n/k + 1)) = O(k)`
- `lim(n->inf) n/k = constant`

  `a = O(2*constant*k + k) = O(another_constant * k) = O(k)`

  `b = O(constant*k + k) = O(another_constant2 * k) = O(k)`
- `lim(n->inf) n/k = inf` => `lim(n->inf) k/n = 0`

  `a = O(n(2 + k/n)) = O(2n) = O(n)`

  `b = O(n(1 + k/n)) = O(n)`

So, in every case this is true.

Comment: Is `k` the number of connected components?

Comment: I don't understand you exactly. The graph is connected, so there is only one component.

Comment: I see, `k` is the number of edges which exceed the minimum number necessary for connectivity.

Comment: Exactly! I've added your explanation in my post to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking seems right to me only with one exception.
Can you be sure that there cannot be two or more edges between two same verticies? So the graph is not **multi-graph**?
Otherwise `m = X  * (n*(n-1))/2` where `X` can grow to infinity and it is a new variable in the problem. Then the complexity would be something like `O(X*n*n)`.

Anyway the equation would still be correct as `+n` in the first clause can be still omitted (because quadratic function "overcharges" linear one).